# How can I use Google Maps geocoder in an angularJs datatable without Exceeding the quota limit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-api-3

I have a datatable in whch I need to find a city name based on lat and lng. I'm trying to use Google maps geocoder in order to reverse coding latitude and longitude into city name. I created a function to do that but I'm getting limit rate exceeded since I have a lot of rows in the datatable.

Is there any way to call the geocoding function only for current active pagination ?

Comment: Go here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits then click on the "Enable Billing" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The geocoding API has rate limit of 50 requests per second and 2,500 per day, calculated as the sum of client-side and server-side queries.

What you should do is add some delay or interval between you geocoding requests in javascript. Maybe a few milliseconds. Just enough so that you are not exceeding 50 requests per second.

Answer (score 0):

Please be careful here!

The Geocoding API has a default quota per day limit of unlimited until you change it yourself.

You can do this on the Google Cloud Console.

Go into 'Google Maps Platform', then into 'quotas', then choose the API from the drop down list at the top, click on 'requests' and then modify 'requests per day'.

This was to clarify information in the first answer.

You can also check 'exponential backoff' here on the Google Maps Platform Docs - https://developers.google.com/maps/optimization-guide#performance